# Powershell DB backup script pass only when executing from ISE

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-ise, bacpac

I've been using following backup script for a while to create .bacpac files for MSSQL databases. The script working ok in general but fails for some databases. Those databases are not too much different to others, maybe a bit bigger. As this is used only for dev databases the average size is not big, the bacpac file size is ~200Mb.

The weird thing the script successfully running when executed from PowerShell ISE but failed when running from the command line. Please note that script only failing for some databases and work for others. The error message is not really helpful:

> WARNING: Exception occurred: Exception calling "ExportBacpac" with "2" argument(s): "Could not export schema and data from database."

We using MSSQL 2104 and the database can be exported to backup from MSSQL Studio without problems.

The script:

```
Param(
    # Database name to backup e.g 'MYDB'
    $databaseName,
    # Database connection string "server=server ip;Integrated Security = True;User ID=user;Password=pass"
    $connectionString,
    # Path to the directory where backup file should be created
    $backupDirectory
)
add-type -path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll";

try {
    $dacService = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices $connectionString
    # build backup filename
    $backupFileName  = $backupDirectory+"\"+$dataBaseName+[DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss")+".bacpac" 
    # perform backup
    $dacService.exportBacpac($backupFileName, $dataBaseName);
    Write-Output "Database backup file created $backupFileName"
} catch {
    Write-warning "Exception occurred: $_"
    throw "Database backup haven't been created, execution aborted."
}
```

Does anyone come across this issue? I know PowerShell and PowerShell ISE a bit different but I don't understand why script execution produces different results.

**[EDIT]**

Tried to add event listener for DacService and print output to get more debug information

```
 register-objectevent -in $dacService -eventname Message -source "msg" -action { out-host -in $Event.SourceArgs[1].Message.Message } | Out-Null
```

The output is

```
Dac Assembly loaded.
Extracting schema (Start)
Gathering database options
Gathering users
WARNING: Exception occurred: Exception calling "ExportBacpac" with "2" argument(s): "Could not export schema and data
from database."
Gathering roles
Gathering application roles
Gathering role memberships
Gathering filegroups
Gathering full-text catalogs
Gathering assemblies
Gathering certificates 
....
Processing Table '[dbo].[file_storage_entity]'. 99.74 % done.
Processing Table '[dbo].[file_storage_entity]'. 100.00 % done.
Exporting data (Failed)
```

**[EDIT 2]**

As a workaround, I've created C# program to do the same. Runs fine in any environment. The code virtually the same as in PowerShell script.

Comment: Try to get more error information using `$_ | fl * -f ` within your catch statement

Comment: Does it always fails for the same databases ? Perhaps you should increase Posh memory settings.

Comment: @majkinetor. I have 3 databases out of 16 for which script is consistently failing. I tried to increase Posh memory according https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/30/learn-how-to-configure-powershell-memory/ but didn't help

Comment: What happens if you try to export bacpac with `SqlPackage.exe` ?

Comment: @majkinetor it exported successfully.

Comment: Could that be enough or you still want powershell way... its pretty hard to diagnose this kind of problem without access to machine.

Comment: @majkinetor the solution is not ideal but livable. Imagine you have access to the machine what would you do? If you can provide plan of attack then it could be a perfect answer.

Comment: @MikhailChibel, I am not sure what would I do, this kind of thing requires ad hoc reasoning, not a plan.

Comment: @MikhailChibel, There can be number of things - something in ISE profile mitigating error, ISE and POSH are different: STA, culture, assemblies etc..